# What can I do for this SCM Error?

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors

Error: 200009 (Illegal target for the requested operation) Description: Commit failed (details follow): 
Error: 200009 (Illegal target for the requested operation) Description: '/Users/mine/Documents/Projects/MyApp/trunk/Resources/Settings.bundle/zh-Hans.lproj' is not under version control and is not part of the commit, yet its child '/Users/mine/Documents/Projects/MyApp/trunk/Resources/Settings.bundle/zh-Hans.lproj/Root.strings' is part of the commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Subversion. This might sort of apply in other cases but the terminology might be wrong.

It seems like part of your tree either got something copied over it which hosed the hidden folder which marks a folder as being under revision control.

The best thing to do is check the tree out again into a different folder with something like:

```
svn co file:///Users/mine/Documents/Projects/MyApp/trunk freshTrunk
```

then copy over changes from the old directory, and commit them.

Once you are satisifed the changes were saved, delete the old directory.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I commit it after commit folder not file itself.